# How the compiler knows where my main function is?

Tags: c, program-entry-point

I am working on a project that contains multiple modules (source files, header files, libraries). One of the files in all that soup contains my main function.

My questions are:

- How the compiler knows which modules to compile and which not?
- How does the compiler recognize the module with the main() inside?

Comment: Read about phases of compiler and you will get the answer.

Comment: It doesn't. [enuf characters for this comment]

Comment: Compiler does not care about main function and will compile all compilation unit. Later linker would link these and may remove unlinked functions.

Comment: It is the duty of the linker. Makefile takes care of it.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler itself doesn't care about what file contains which functions; `main()` is not special. However, in the linking stage, all these symbols from different files (and compilation units, possibly) are matched. The linker has a hidden "template" which has code at a fixed address that the OS will always call when you run a program. That code will call your `main`; hence, the linker looks for a `main` in all files. If it isn't there, you get an unresolved symbol error, exactly like if you used a function that you forgot to implement.

The same as for any other function applies to `main`: You can only have *one* implementation; having two `main` in two files that get linked together, you get a linker error, because the linker can't decide which of these to use.

Comment: More specifically: when the compiler is called in linking mode, it acts as a driver that refers to the C library's special runtime code. The fixed address in the executable header is typically the address of a symbol called `_start`.

Answer (score 1):

> *How the compiler knows which modules to compile and which not*?

It does not. You tell *him* which ones *you* want to compile, typically though the compilation statement(s) present in a makefile.

> *How does the compiler recognize the module with the main() inside?*

Altogether it's a big process, already answered in [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5202709/2173917).

To summarize, while compiling a program with standard C library, the entry point of your program is set to `_start`. Now that has a reference to `main()` function internally. So, at compilation time, there is no (need for) checking the presence of `main()`. At linking time, linker should be able to locate **one** instance of `main()` which it can link to. That way, `main()` will serve as the entry point to your program.

So, to answer

> *How the compiler knows where my main function is?*

It does (and need) not. It's the job of a linker, specifically.

Answer (score 0):

The assembly code (often referred as startup code by embedded people) that starts up the program specifically calls `main()`.
The prototype for `main()` is included in compiler documentation. 
When you compile a program, an object file is produced. The object file from your source code is then linked with a startup runtime component (usually called crt0.o[bj]) and the C library components, etc.
If `main()` is changed to an unrecognizable signature, the compilation unit will complain about an unresolved external reference to `_main` or `__main`.